# How metamask restores account information using seed words?

Tags: metamask

Metamask don't store keys on any server. Metamask stores your private keys using your browser's data store.

Then how can metamask restores accounts using seed words without storing it anywhere ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metamask doesn't store keys or any data of wallet on server , actually the mnemonic generated by metamask when you create the wallet has the capability to generate the private key, public key and ethereum address .

This mnemonic is called BIP39 seed phrase,and it can be used to regenerate the private key of your wallet , private key can generate the public key and public key is used to generate ethreum address. So this feature is not specific to metamask , it is the property of BIP39 mnemonic to encode the private key of your wallet. That's why you should keep your mnemonic pass phrase secretly .

For further information you can access the link :-
https://silentcicero.gitbooks.io/pro-tips-for-ethereum-wallet-management/content/ethereum-wallet-basics/using-seed-phrases-to-create-ethereum-accounts.html

There is an online tool which you can use to regenerate all the information of your wallet using the seed phrase:-https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Comment: Probably not a good idea to enter your seed phrase anywhere online.

Comment: yes , it is never a good idea to enter your seed phrase online anywhere :) and not recommended in any situation, answer is just for educational purpose to describe how Metamask or any wallet works . :)